# Does the limit of this multivariable function exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I found this excercise in Thomas Calculus (12th edition), Chapter 14, excercise 51:

$$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
1 & y\ge x^4 \\
1 & y \le 0 \\
0 & otherwise
\end{cases}
$$

Find the following limit, or explain that the limit does not exist: $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y)$

From the solution manual we get the folloing answer:

Along $x = 0 : \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y) = 1$

Along $y=x^2 : \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y) = 0 $

Therefore $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y)$ does not exist

But near $(0,0)$ we have that $x^2 \gt x^4$ which means that the second limit falls within the first case and that equals 1. Instead of $y=x^2$ we could get $y=x^6$ and reach the same conclusion. Am I right?

Comment: You are right. Take $y=x^{6}$.